# How to fetch the data from database while selecting a select option from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, database, codeigniter, fetch

I am using codeigniter for my project and I am passing array values on view.

Let me elaborate by giving a proper look to the view, controller and model structure.

Model:

```
public function getTournament() {
    $this->db->select('tourn_id,tourn_name,tourn_teams');
    $this->db->from('tournaments');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function index() {
    $result['tournament']=$this->matches_model->getTournament();
    $this->template->set_layout('admin')->enable_parser(FALSE)->title('Add Matches - Cricnepal Live Update')->build('admin/add/matches_view', $result);
}
```

View:

```
<select name="tournament_match" class="form-control" id="tournament_match">
    <option value=''>--- Select Tournament ---</option>
    <?php 
        foreach ($tournament as $row):
            $match_TournamentName=$row['tourn_name'];
            $match_TournamentID=$row['tourn_id'];
            $teamlist=$row['tourn_teams'];
            echo '<option value='.$match_TournamentID.'>'.$match_TournamentName.'</option>'; 
        endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```

Problem:

```
<select name="tournament_match" class="form-control" id="tournament_match">
      <option value="">--- Select Tournament ---</option>
      <option value="1">Cricnepal Cricket Tournament</option>
      <option value="2">Nepal Cricket Tournament</option>
</select>
```

I want to display a new select option field below it which shows the data of respected selected option value.

For example, if I select "Cricnepal Cricket Tournament" then I need to get all the associated data related to it from the database instantly using jQuery or other method so it can be added as a new option element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your `html` will go:

```
<select name="tournament_match" class="form-control" id="tournament_match">
      <option value="">--- Select Tournament ---</option>
      <option value="1">Cricnepal Cricket Tournament</option>
      <option value="2">Nepal Cricket Tournament</option>
</select>
<select name="second_select" id="second_select"></select>
```

And your `js` will be:

```
$('#tournament_match').change(function() {
   var selected_option = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      url: <YOUR URL TO HANDLE THE REQUEST>+"/"+selected_option,
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      success: function(return_data) {
         $('#second_select').html(return_data);
      }
   });
});
```

And the `php` to handle the ajax request will be like this:

```
$newoptions = ['apples','oranges','bananas']; //values from the db or some api source.
$ret_val = '';
foreach($newoptions as $option) {
   $ret_val .= "<option>$option</option>";
}
echo $ret_val;
```

There you go buddy. I don't think you should have a problem anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jquery 'ajax' call like below:

```
$('#tournament_match').change(function() {
   var selected_option = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      url: <YOUR URL TO HANDLE THE REQUEST>+"/"+selected_option,
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      success: function(return_data) {
         $('#second_select').html(return_data);
      }
   });
});
```

Where 'second_select' is the id of the second drop down.

Comment: Thank for the reply. Let me check on it and will post it

Comment: Okay let me know if run into any problem.

Comment: The jquery code is not functioning .. i tried by doing alert (some value) but it is not showing up any things .. is there is any syntax error ??

Comment: Thank You !!!  you made my work ...thank you so much ...really i dont know how to express now ...thank you

Comment: The url part in the ajax was mistake by me so it was getting a bit problem for so much time....

Comment: I had a problem again ..while appending on a second dropdown box ... after changing each time ... it going updating rather it need to be refreshed ...any solution??

Comment: I am sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: Once I change the select option first  .. it displays the exact thing i want ... it appends the next select option. but now when i change to another option of the first select option then ... i will show both append values the previous one and current one ... which it shouldnt be .... like example:
when i click on cricnepal cricket tournament ... it displays 4 option in another select otion ....
but when i again change the first slection into Nepal cricket tournament then it should show 2 values in second option .. but it is showing 6 option in 2nd select option ....

Comment: How are you doing the appending? Are u appending a new select everytime the option is changed?

Comment: for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++){
     
     $('#tournament_team').append('<select><option value="'+ array[i] +'">'+ array[i]+'</option></select>');
     
   

    }

Comment: for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++){
     
     $('#tournament_team').append('<option value="'+ array[i] +'">'+ array[i]+'</option><');
     
   

    }

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: 'matches/checkid/'+id,
      type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(return_data) {
    var data = return_data
    
    var array = data.split(',');
    
    
    for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++){
     
     $('#tournament_team').append('<option value="'+ array[i] +'">'+ array[i]+'</option>');
      
    }

      }
   
  });

Comment: The array is that ... when i get the value from the ajax .. it has to separate the teams name by comma which i have to place it in a array and show then that splitted value to the second select option

Comment: Should it not be like, that you use two '<select>'s, Adding more options to the same select doesn't make sense to me.
What I think is that, when the user selects an option from the first '<select>', the respective options should be loaded into the second '<select>'.

Comment: And you can return the ajax response in the form of html markup, in that way you won't have to split them in javascript.

Comment: Ya exactly that what i wanted .... can you explain to that ... i was wondering on this way ... to be complex ...

Comment: Take a look at my answer again, there is a single statement in the success callback, it says $('#second_select').html(ret_data). You need to create another select element in your page, with an id of 'second_select'. And from your ajax response return html markup for the options. like echo '<option value="$val">$val</option>', and those will be loaded into the second select automatically.

Comment: i didn't got it ... please give a example in detail .. i am sorry i am bothering u ....

Comment: Check the new answer plz.